# Open My Site in new window or tab

Tags: 2010

Environ: SP 2010 Enterprise.

When a user navigates to My Site from our website there is no way to come back to the original site (unless they hit the back button - which makes business users annoyed!). Is there a workaround for this?
If nothing else works, I'd at least like to have the My Site open in a new window. Google yielded a [javascript option and a user control option](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/fdd1e900-4414-409b-a1d2-f1f6d8bf0ddb/). I can't add usercontrols and the javascript doesn't work for me.
Can someone please help?

Comment: The javascript should work. Adding `target="_blank"` is the way to make links open in new tab/window. Can you revisit this solution ? Maybe edit manually the page with `F12` and try adding the property yourself.

Comment: I can't edit the page with designer. I added the JS in a CEWP. Do you think that's why its not working?

Comment: If you do so, you must wait till the Document is loaded. Event that, check in the source code of the page if your Javascript is still there. SharePoint "cleans" the Content of CEWP when saved. For example, CSS Background are not supported (erased). If you have jQuery, here is the code to wait for the Document to load : `$(document).ready(function() {
  // Code goes here
});`

Answer (score 2):

The global breadcrumb (tan folder with a green up arrow) can be configured to provide a path back to the main site.

Another option would be to add a location to the links within the MySite config in CA.  Browse to the User profile service app and under the My Site Settings group click the Configure Personalization Site link.  From here you can add a new link and specify the audience if appropriate.  This will add an additional link to the My Site navigation to the right of the My Newsfeed, My Content and My Profile links.

Third option would be to add it to the top nav of each site collection.  This can be done via a PowerShell script if you need to automate it.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to see examples of the options listed above? E.g. in the case of the first option, I do not have a breadcrumb in My Site. And I don't have admin rights to check the config either.

Comment: There isn't a lot you can do for all sites if you don't have access.  If you want to fix just your site, you can add it to the navigation manually.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer on another post and it worked for me.

From the SharePoint UI, edit your navigation link and enter the web address in the following format:

```
javascript: void(window.open('http://www.google.com'));
```